# Does async task gets killed before its completion if so what happens to life cycle of calling activity when async task is stopped?

Tags: android-asynctask

I have an Activity A which has a task that needs to be performed in background. So i'm sending the task to async. What happens to activity life cycle when the

```
myAsyncTask.cancel(true)
```

is called i.e async task is killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to stop AsyncTask,

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

and for "what will happen to life cycle of calling activity" i dont know much, you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) for life cycle of an activity, but as the async task is performed in background the activity will continue to work, but after stopping the asynctask according to documentation found in android studio

> The default implementation simply invokes onCancelled() and ignores the result. If you write your own implementation, do not call super.onCancelled(result).

you can do your own implemetation of how to handle after stoping from async task, and after this may be the activity life cycle will be resumed and work normally.

I am not confirmed about this, but let me know if i am wrong somewhere.